# How is a "Split" Air Conditioner Heat Pump System different from a garden variety Heat Pump?

Tags: hvac

I would like to replace my 4-ton HVAC (for a my storage facility, requiring only cooling), which is similar to this [Goodman device](https://www.ebay.com/itm/173301683806).    Assume the site is in North Florida (Jacksonville).  There is no duct work in the storage facility as the air handler pumps the cool air into a central hallway and diffuses into each storage unit.  The purpose of cooling is not for human comfort, rather it is to control humidity.

It would seem that the benefits of the `Ducted Central Split` (DCS) Heatpump is better efficiency:  [this 4-ton example is rated at 21.5-Seer](https://dealzer.com/ideal-air-pro-dual-48-000-btu-21-5-seer-multi-zone-heating-cooling-outdoor-unit/).

I am trying to get a handle on the differences so I understand the pros and cons of DCS  & existing heat pumps.  Heat (heat pump) is a nice to have, however keeping it cool is the requirement.

Is the DCS device somehow more efficient that the Goodman-style device?  Why are homes outfitted with duct endpoints and not DCS style endpoints?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about home improvement but a storage facility.

Comment: @JACK Is there a better stack exchange site for my question?  This question is equally applicable to the home and would benefit users to learn the subject matter.  I suspect that the split system is superior to the machines I have been sold by the local AC shops.

Comment: Every company maintenance person and commercial business could make the same arguement and if we accept them all, the poor homeowner will be out of luck. We're not a discussion forum. That's what the internet's for.  Plus, in your comment to Harper, you're point blank asking for a product recommendation whch is a big no no.

Comment: @JACK Would it be satisfactory to remove the context / details of where and how it is to be used?  Please consider editing the question to your satisfaction

Answer (score 1):

In America, the air conditioning business was a huge thing for at least 60 years.  The vast majority of American homes have A/C, while it is rare in Europe with similar per-capita GDP. The production plants have been scaled up to put A/C units on the entire country.

**Unfortunately, this has bred an industry that is VERY "stuck in the mud" technologically**. They're all about getting the longest life out of the old plants they've already invested in, and if that means they keep making That 70s Air Conditioner, well the market can suck it. Only very begrudgingly, they make tiny efficiency improvements when the government forces them to.

The upshot is that European, Japanese and Korean manufacturers have embarrassingly "lapped" the stodgy old American A/C makers in both functionality and efficiency.  18 SEER *isn't even particularly good*.  I've seen reports of units as high as 38 SEER.

They're efficient because they're scratch-built for the 21st century.  It has nothing to do with being a heat pump; they are heat pumps because the 21st century market also wants that.

The mini-split form-factor is fantastic for retrofit; which is the market in Europe and Asia.  The vast majority of American installations are already committed to "air handler and ducts".  But that's not a problem; modern outdoor head-units can be matched up to condenser/evaporators that go in the air handling system.

Unfortunately the production scale of Those 70's Air Conditioners is so vast that they still *define* the lower cost market, especially where professional installers are involved.  DIY mini-splits are the best deal in town for the DIYer.

Comment: Thank you for commenting.  I was sensing what you said: Asia / Caribbean / South America has the "split" style cool and not the "duct".   I'd like to DIY a split style (with inverter)  for both efficiency and aesthetic reasons.  If you have a link to a 48000 BTU 38 Seer that you recommend, I would appreciate you posting this example in your answer.  Thank you

Comment: It is my understanding that the standard central a/c is a "split" system because the evaporator coil and air handler "duct blower" are inside and so physically separated from the condensing unit outside. It is also a "heat pump" in that it transfers heat from inside to outside to cool the interior in hot weather. However it seems that the term heat pump is now reserved for a unit which can be reversed and also transfer heat from outside to inside in cold weather. An example of a non-split system would be a window unit.

Comment: @JimStewart.   I think this should be an answer to the question and I suspect that your answer is right.  The absence of duct work is a notable feature and in all likeliness an efficiency advantage.   Efficiency may be the reason why we do not see air handler ducted systems in the Caribbean and Asia homes

Comment: @gatorback keep in mind America only went with forced-air ducted systems when they wanted A/C.  Every pre-1960 home I've lived in did not have ducts, and had water or electric baseboards or wall furnaces.  But when you are in the ducted world, makers of traditional "That 70's A/C" units just flood the market with their 14 SEER carpola, so the efficient units have trouble competing on price into small residential installs.  Institutional where you have certified A/C guys on staff, absolutely.

Comment: Anyway, heat pump search engine here.  https://ashp.neep.org/#!/product_list/ . Unfortunately these guys are all about heating and don't expose SEER numbers directly in the search engine.  Also I may be making the same error Technology Connections made while searching. https://youtu.be/43XKfuptnik?t=1093 By the way that whole series (well, videos 1 3 and 4 anyway) are first rate, the "ground sourced" video is wrong.